# How to convert a generic list from and to Java.Lang.Object in Mono for Android

Tags: c#, java, xamarin.android

Now I'm facing this problem and don't know about a solution yet. The doc on Xamarin is pretty vague to me on this matter. The fact that Java Generics are implemented as type erase which is quite different from .NET's approach also makes the matter quite complex. Could anyone point me to the right direction?
It seems that the generic type parameter should implement IJavaObject, but I did this and it does not work in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I'll have to answer it myself. After contacting Xamarin, in the case of using a list to do things which requires it to be a IJavaObject, you'd better off with JavaList instead of List which also implements IList. JavaList actually is just a wrapper around java.util.ArrayList

Comment: General idea is that we need to use C# wrapper for Java types if we are to interop with java types