# Java cast ArrayList to C#

Tags: java, c#, java-native-interface

Need to cast a Java ArrayList to C# ArrayList.

It does not work.

```
//code in C#
public void DoSomething(Java.Lang.Object obj){
    Java.Util.ArrayList list = (Java.Util.ArrayList) obj;
}
```

The Exception:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

When I print out `obj.Class`, it returns `class java.util.ArrayList`

How to fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581407/how-can-i-convert-arraylistobject-to-arrayliststring

Comment: @Generic That s not what I am asking.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to cast a java.util.ArrayList to a Java.Util.ArrayList.  Does not look like they are the same thing so you will not be able to cast.  The Java.Util.ArrayList might be a List can you cast to the interface?

Comment: same Exception when casting to Java.Util.IList. What did you want me to cast it to?

Comment: You guys DO know that I'm trying to do C# with Java Objects here right? I mean all your comments are assuming that it's all in Java when I specifically stated that the code is in C#.

Comment: This doen't make a lot of sense.  What is `p0`?  What makes you think it *should* be possible to cast from a Java type to a C# type?

Comment: OK. That was my mistake. `p0` is actually `obj`. If it is not possible, then how do I access the list of data in obj? Or do people pass in data from Java to C# for fun and not to process it?

Comment: As clarification for me: this code you posted is c# code? and the object is a "java" object? how did you get this java object?

Comment: maybe this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527408/how-to-convert-a-generic-list-from-and-to-java-lang-object-in-mono-for-android

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: Did you try `obj.JavaCast<Java.Util.ArrayList>` ?

Comment: Unless you are using a library similar to IKVM.NET (as proposed in the other answer) or http://jni4net.com the lowest common denominator between Java and C# is that both have low-level C interfaces. In that case what you get from Java is a C pointer to a Java object and you need to use JNI (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html) to manipulate it. If you are using a library, please let us know which one?

Answer (score 12):

I do not write C# code but if this was me and I needed to convert an object for use in a different language I would just serialize the Java object to JSON and deserialize it to my object in C#.

Comment: This is also how I would approach it. Serialize the object into JSON or some string representation of the data that is easy to parse. Depending on the size and way the method is called and data passed, I may also compress with something like MessagePack.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need this amazing library: https://www.ikvm.net/ by Jeroen Frijters & contributors.

> IKVM.NET is an implementation of Java for Mono and the Microsoft .NET Framework. It includes the following components:
>
> A Java Virtual Machine implemented in .NET
> A .NET implementation of the Java class libraries
> Tools that enable Java and .NET interoperability

This is such a massive subject, you'll have to do a few tutorials, eg [Convert a Java Application to .NET](https://sourceforge.net/p/ikvm/wiki/Tutorial/#convert-a-java-application-to-net). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It is ready in Xamarin, just add:

```
using Android.Gms.Extensions;
```

then:

```
var list = listAsObject.JavaCast<ArrayList>();
```